# Is there any difference between 学園 and 学校?

Tags: meaning, words

[学校]{がっ・こう} is usually one of the first words we encounter when learning Japanese, however the use of [学園]{がく・えん} also seems pretty common in media. Is there any practical difference between the two terms or are they interchangeable in general?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

学園 is commonly translated as "Academy". Basically it is nothing more than a naming convention which is arbitrarily adopted for the names of some schools (including 中学校, 高校, 大学, [予備校](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yobik%C5%8D) and 塾). So all schools called 学園 are technically also 学校, but the opposite is not true. As a minor exception, 学園 is found in some place names of science parks and university towns (e.g., [筑波研究学園都市](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsukuba,_Ibaraki)). 学院 is almost the same but it's not used as a place name.

Most real 学園/学院 in Japan are private schools, but there are a few exceptions. In addition, I feel that schools that are considered "unique", "classy" or "special" in some way or another tend to be called 学園/学院. For example, [Christian schools in Japan](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E7%B3%BB%E9%AB%98%E7%AD%89%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1) are commonly called ～学園 or ～学院. In fiction, students in [*Kaguya-sama*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaguya-sama:_Love_Is_War) and the [*Toaru*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Certain_Magical_Index) franchise go to schools called ～学園. 魔法学園 are very common in fantasy works.